# No Markup in Haddock Docs Section

Tags: haskell, formatting, markup, haddock

I have an ASCII diagram in a module's documentation that I would like to display in haddock, however I cannot figure out how to turn off markup for that section of the comments so that it doesn't treat characters as markup / special characters.

Does anyone know a way to do this? I'm looking for something that doesn't involve escaping the problem characters inline because that makes the diagram less legible when viewing the source.

The diagram in question looks like this:

```
    [+/-round]  [+/-anterior][+/-distrib]  [+/-high][+/-low][+/-back]  [+/-ATR]
         |                |    |                  \    |    /            |
       [labial]          [coronal]                 [dorsal]        [pharyngeal]
          \_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | _  _ _ _ _ _ _/
                                           |
                                         PLACE
                                           |
                                       X segment
                                   (+/- consonantal)
                                    (+/- sonorant)
             _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
            |                  |           |             |         |
     [+/-continuant]    [+/-strident]   [lateral]   [nasal]   [laryngeal]
                                                              /    |    \
                                                            [SG]  [CG]  [+/-voice]
```

Comment: Do [`>`-style code blocks](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html#idm140354810780208) do what you need?

Comment: Thank you. I had been using an @-style code block, and the escaped characters were a problem there. The >-style code block works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of code blocks. One kind, bracketed in front and in back by `@`, allow nested markup, e.g. to write example code that links to the documentation of the API calls mentioned in it. The other kind, where each line is prefaced by `>`, is not interpreted further (i.e. does not allow nested markup).

The second kind should be suitable for including this kind of diagram.